# Вывести значение JSON ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, json-encode

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите в чем дело? Вот я вытягиваю из базы данных информацию. Она выводиться в файле обработчике через PDO: `json_encode($sql->fetchAll());`

Далее вот это добро выводится ajax'ом в нужный файл. Выводится примерно в таком виде:

```
[
    {
        "id_usr": "36",
        "login_usr": "login3",
        "password_usr": "aqwerty"
    },
    {
        "id_usr": "35",
        "login_usr": "login2",
        "password_usr": "aqwerty"
    },
    {
        "id_usr": "34",
        "login_usr": "login1",
        "password_usr": "aqwerty"
    }
]
```

Далее я пытаюсь ее вывести через javascript примерно так: `data['id_usr']`. Но мне выводится: `undefined`

В чем тут дело? Я неправильно вывожу JSON значения, которые пришли ajax'ом?

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас данные по каждому юзеру являются объектом (ассоциативным массивом) и он является элементом другого массива. Вот пример доступа ко всем элементам по порядку в цикле

```
var arr = [
    {
        "id_usr": "36",
        "login_usr": "login3",
        "password_usr": "aqwerty"
    },
    {
        "id_usr": "35",
        "login_usr": "login2",
        "password_usr": "aqwerty"
    },
    {
        "id_usr": "34",
        "login_usr": "login1",
        "password_usr": "aqwerty"
    }
];
for(var i in arr) {
  alert(arr[i].id_usr);
  alert(arr[i].login_usr);
  alert(arr[i].password_usr);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8zaq076/

Comment: Ваш пример работает. Но только если готовый массив. А если тоже самое делать с ajax запросами, то ничего не выходит :(

Comment: Проблема решена. Я не указал `dataType: "json"` в самом ajax запросе. Проблема решена. Спасибо!